# how to generate summary table with latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have an action table with some dummy records as below:

```
create table action
(
userid int
,date datetime
,action varchar(5)
)

insert into action values(1, '2017-03-24 00:00:00','1')
insert into action values(2, '2017-03-24 00:00:00','2')
insert into action values(3, '2017-03-24 00:00:00','1')
insert into action values(4, '2017-03-24 00:00:00','2')
insert into action values(4, '2017-03-24 00:01:00','1')
insert into action values(5, '2017-03-24 00:00:00','1')

insert into action values(1, '2017-03-23 00:00:00','1')
insert into action values(2, '2017-03-23 00:00:00','1')
insert into action values(3, '2017-03-23 00:00:00','2')
insert into action values(4, '2017-03-23 00:00:00','1')
insert into action values(1, '2017-03-23 00:01:00','2')
insert into action values(2, '2017-03-23 00:02:00','2')
insert into action values(1, '2017-03-23 00:03:00','1')
insert into action values(2, '2017-03-23 00:05:00','1')
```

I want to generate a summary table so that for each user, it shows the latest status of that day. The result would be like the following.

```
create table summary
(
userid int
,date datetime
,status varchar(5)
)

date    userid  status
2017-03-24  1   1
2017-03-24  2   2
2017-03-24  3   1
2017-03-24  4   1
2017-03-24  5   1
2017-03-23  1   1
2017-03-23  2   1
2017-03-23  3   2
2017-03-23  4   1
```

I tried using row_number() over (partition by userid order by date desc)
but the result wasn't as expected.

Any help please?
I'm using sql server but any database syntax are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to partition by the date:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by a.userid, cast(a.date as date)
                                order by a.date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from action a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the quick response, this is awesome！

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
INSERT INTO [summary]
SELECT a.userid
,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]))
, a.[action] 
FROM [action] a
WHERE a.[date] IN 
(
SELECT MAX([date]) 
FROM [action] a1 WHERE a.userid = a1.userid 
GROUP BY userid, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]))
)
```